# Spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $[Z, X]_{\bullet} \cong [Z, Y]_{\bullet}$ for all cogroup objects $Z$ in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Edit:** As there are many comments and an answer already, I have left the original question below.

I was unaware that there are different ways one could try to define $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, 'the' homotopy category of pointed topological spaces. The two that were discussed in the comments were:

1. the category with pointed topological spaces as objects and morphisms given by base-point preserving homotopy classes of maps (i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) = [X, Y]_{\bullet}$), and
2. the category $\mathsf{Top}_{\bullet}$ localised at weak homotopy equivalences.

If I'm not mistaken, Zhen Lin was referring to the first while Najib Idrissi was referring to the second. When I asked the question, I was thinking about the first category so the questions below remain unanswered.

With this in mind, I'm now a little concerned about the difference between homotopy equivalent and base-point preserving homotopy equivalent. For example, the comb space $C$ is homotopy equivalent to a point (i.e. contractible), but $(0, 1)$ is not a strong deformation retract of $C$, so $(C, (0, 1))$ is not base-point preserving homotopy equivalent to a point. I'm not sure if this distinction will play a role in answering question $1$.

---

Throughout, $(X, x_0)$ and $(Y, y_0)$ will be connected pointed topological spaces.

If $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ is a continuous map and $f_* : \pi_n(X, x_0) \to \pi_n(Y, y_0)$ is an isomorphism for $n > 0$, then $f$ is called a weak homotopy equivalence. The Whitehead Theorem states that if $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes, then a weak homotopy equivalence is in fact a homotopy equivalence.

Note, the existence of a map $f$ which induces isomorphisms of homotopy groups is necessary as there are CW complexes which have isomorphic homotopy groups but are not homotopy equivalent; for example, $S^2\times\mathbb{RP}^3$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^3$ (they have different second integral homology).

The $n^{\text{th}}$ homotopy group of a space $X$ can be defined as $[S^n, X]_{\bullet}$ which denotes the pointed homotopy classes of maps from $S^n$ to $X$. This is a group because spheres are cogroup objects in the category $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$. There are other cogroup objects in this category, including (but not limited to) suspensions of arbitrary topological spaces.

With this in mind, my first question is:

> **Question $1$:** If $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ is a continuous map such that $f_* : [Z, X]_{\bullet} \to [Z, Y]_{\bullet}$ is an isomorphism for every cogroup object $Z$ in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, are $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent?

If the answer to question $1$ is yes, my next question is

> **Question $2\, (a)$:** If $[Z, X]_{\bullet} \cong [Z, Y]_{\bullet}$ for every cogroup object $Z$ in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, are $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent?

If the answer to question $1$ is no, my next question is

> **Question $2\, (b)$:** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of cogroup objects in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$. For which $\mathcal{F}$ is the following true: if $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ induces isomorphisms $f_* : [Z, X]_{\bullet} \to [Z, Y]_{\bullet}$ for all $Z \in \mathcal{F}$, then $X$ and $Y$ are weakly homotopy equivalent.

Furthermore, is there a finite such $\mathcal{F}$? Is there an analogue of Whitehead's Theorem for all such $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Maybe I'm remembering the hypotheses wrong, but if $f : X \to Y$ is a weak equivalence then its image in the homotopy category is always an isomorphism, thus by the Yoneda embedding $f_* : \hom_\mathsf{Ho(C)}(-, X) \to \hom_\mathsf{Ho(C)}(-, Y)$ is a natural isomorphism no matter what. So a weak homotopy equivalence which isn't a strong homotopy equivalence gives a counterexample for Q1, no? (In the model category of pointed spaces where weak equivalences are weak homotopy equivalences)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Of course, there is also the other option, where the weak equivalences are actual homotopy equivalences.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It seems to me that the answer to Q1 is yes when $X$ and $Y$ are pointed connected CW-complexes. Indeed, by adjointness, we have for every pointed (but not necessarily connected) $Z$ a natural bijection $\mathbf{hTop}_* (Z, \Omega X) \to \mathbf{hTop}_* (Z, \Omega Y)$, so $\Omega f : \Omega X \to \Omega Y$ is a homotopy equivalence, so $f : X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm not sure I understand your first comment, but for your second, you can directly use Whitehead's theorem (the spheres are cogroups and $[S^n, X]_\bullet = \pi_n(X)$). Unless I'm missing something (which is not unlikely).

Comment: Sure, we could do that too. But the adjointness argument I suggest says that $\Omega f : \Omega X \to \Omega Y$ really is a homotopy equivalence, whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are CW-complexes.

Comment: @ZhenLin This is were I'm confused, actually. Is it well-known that if for all (not necessarily connected, but since we're taking based maps anyway...) $Z$, $\mathsf{hTop}_*(Z, \Omega X) \to \mathsf{hTop}_*(Z, \Omega Y)$ is a bijection, then $\Omega f$ is a homotopy equivalence? Where does the structure of $\Omega$ intervenes?

Comment: That we have a loop space is irrelevant. This is just an application of the fact that the isomorphisms in $\mathbf{hTop}_*$ are the based homotopy equivalences.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Would you mind turning your first comment into an answer (for question 1)?

Comment: @ZhenLin If I'm not mistaken, only isomorphisms in $\mathsf{hTop}_*$ *between fibrant-cofibrant objects* are automatically based (strong) homotopy equivalences, right? In general you can't invert weak equivalences, AFAIK...

Comment: I use the classical definition of $\mathbf{hTop}_*$ – the morphisms are based homotopy classes of based maps. So the isomorphisms are based homotopy equivalences. (Model structures are not the only way of defining homotopy categories.)

Comment: @ZhenLin: You and Najib seem to be using different definitions of $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$. Is that the case or are they the same, just constructed differently?

Comment: They are different. You should clarify which one you mean.

Comment: @ZhenLin: What are the objects in your definition? Are they pointed topological spaces or pointed CW complexes?

Comment: Pointed topological spaces.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I am using the same definition as you.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1 (per request).

*Note: This answer uses the definition of $[X,Y]_\bullet$ from model category theory. So essentially $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathsf{Top}_\bullet)$ is the localization of $\mathsf{Top}_\bullet$ at weak equivalences, and $\hom_{\operatorname{Ho}(\mathsf{Top}_\bullet)}(X,Y) = \hom_{\mathsf{Top}_\bullet}(Q_X, R_Y) / \sim$ where $Q_X$ is a cofibrant replacement of $X$ and $R_Y$ is a fibrant replacement of $Y$. Cofibrant objects are retracts of generalized CW-complexes, and all objects are fibrant. This is not necessarily the definition you want.*

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a *weak* homotopy equivalence. Put on $\mathsf{Top}_*$ the standard model structure where weak equivalences are weak homotopy equivalences, fibrations are Serre fibrations and cofibrations are determined via lifting properties (I believe they're retracts of generalized CW-complex inclusions). Then $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathsf{Top}_*)$ is the localization of $\mathsf{Top}_*$ at the class of weak homotopy equivalences, and $[A,B]_\bullet = \hom_{\operatorname{Ho}(\mathsf{Top}_*}(A,B)$. Then $f$ is mapped to an isomorphism in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathsf{Top}_*)$ (by definition), thus it's mapped by the Yoneda embedding to a natural isomorphism $$f_* : [-, X]_\bullet \cong [-, Y]_\bullet.$$

In particular $f_*$ is a bijection for all pointed spaces $Z$, not just cogroups, whenever $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. Now just pick some $f$ which is a weak homotopy equivalence but not a strong homotopy equivalence to conclude (for example, the inclusion of a point in the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) is a weak equivalence, but the long line is not contractible).

Comment: For question 2, my intuition tells me that a finite $\mathcal{F}$ cannot work, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Sorry. I was unaware that there were two different possible meanings for $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, namely the one you are using and the one Zhen Lin is using. I'm using the same definition as Zhen Lin. It's up to you, but I still think it is worth keeping your answer here.

Comment: Yes, I realized later @MichaelAlbanese. I think the one you use is more standard, the one I use would rather be denoted as $\hom_{\operatorname{ho}(\mathsf{Top}_*)}(-,-)$ or something.